# Desktop program does not have permission to loadlibrary dll in uwp app directory, all path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\xxxx\xxxx.dll

Tags: loadlibrary

I want to  loadlibrary a dll in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\AppleInc.itunes\，maybe,it is UWP apps directory,but my app is win32 program. when it  loadlibrary,will return 5(Access denied),even if it have rights of administrators. 
if I copy C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\AppleInc.itunes to other partition,it can loadlibrary success,but I don't want to do that.
Does anyone know how to do that?tks!